# c++ multithreaded singleton - anything wrong with this code

Tags: c++, multithreading, singleton

```
template <typename T, typename Lock>
class Singleton
{
public:
static T * getInstance()
{
    if (obj == 0)
    {
        lock.lock();
        if (obj == 0)
        {
            obj = new T;
        }
        lock.unlock();
    }
    return obj;
}

void deleteInstance()
{
   delete obj;
   obj = 0;
}

private:
volatile static T * obj = 0;
static Lock lock; // some sort of mutex
Singleton();
~Singleton();
Singleton(const Singleton &);
Singleton & operator=(const Singleton &);
};
```

Is it necessary that the obj has to be volatile? If the first thread, creates the T instance and lets say the 2nd thread already loaded obj with 0 in the cache before that, will the modern processors  cache gets invalidated or is it possible the 2nd thread might use the 0 value of obj and create T 2nd time? assuming that both threads are running in different cores.

Also please let me know any issues that can come up with using static T * instead of static T as the singleton data.

Comment: WTF does this class have an assignment operator for?  If it's doing its job at all properly, *there will never be another instance to assign.*

Comment: @cHao that's why it's private, to disallow copying...

Comment: @Luchian: Shouldn't it be deleted, then?

Comment: Where you said `Delete T` and `return T`, don't you mean to say `delete obj` and `return obj` ?

Comment: @cHao not if there's no C++11 support.

Comment: I keep forgetting there are compilers out there that don't do C++11  yet :P

Comment: Biggest 'wrong' is that it is Singleton template. That smells like you want to have lot of Singletons while in practice there is rarely need for such thing in C++ project.

Answer (score 3):

The `getInstance()` method is using [double-checked locking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking). Double-checked locking is inherently dangerous because a race condition may be introduced depending on how the compiler generates code for the line:

```
obj = new T;
```

This line essentially involves the following three steps:

1. Allocate `sizeof (T)` bytes.
2. Construct a `T` object in the allocated space.
3. Assign a pointer to the allocated space to `obj`.

The problem is, a compiler is not required to generate code that performs those steps in order. It could, for example, allocate `sizeof (T)` bytes, then assign `obj`, *then* construct `T` in-place. In that scenario, there is a race condition where two different threads can construct a new `T` object. Also, two different threads can attempt to construct a `T` object in the same place.

See [C++ and the Perils of Double-Checked Locking](http://www.aristeia.com/Papers/DDJ_Jul_Aug_2004_revised.pdf) by Scott Meyers and Andrei Alexandrescu.

As far as `deleteInstance()`, you probably shouldn't provide such a function because it allows you to accidentally make the error of deleting the `T` object while other threads are still using it.

**EDIT:** An implementation of `getInstance()` that avoids double-checked locking is:

```
static T * getInstance()
{
    lock.lock();
    if (!obj)
    {
        try
        {
            obj = new T;
        }
        catch (...)
        {
            obj = NULL;
            lock.unlock();
            throw;
        }
    }
    lock.unlock();
    return obj;
}
```

Comment: @Daniel Trebbien - can you advise how it needs to be written

Comment: @Medicine: I added an implementation of `getInstance()` to my answer that avoids double-checked locking.

Comment: @DanielTrebbien - what lucas1024 mentioned above, there is no double checking problem with my code as well as the obj=new T is inside the critical section. The way you implemented is more expensive I think as even after the singleton gets instantiated for the first time, you still want to lock/unlock which are expensive.

Comment: I take my comment back - Daniel is right! Thanks for the link!

Comment: Double-check locking can be made to work in C++11 or using compiler extensions. http://mortoray.com/2012/02/28/double-checked-locking-why-doesnt-it-work-and-how-to-fix-it/

Answer (score 2):

The `getInstance` is fine, and there's no need to make the member `volatile`.

There is however a problem with `deleteInstance`, which can potentially do a double delete (even after a check for `NULL`) if it's called from different threads.

Another problem is that `deleteInstance` doesn't reset `obj` to `NULL`, so after a delete, `getInstance` will return a dangling pointer, not create a new object.

Comment: can you elaborate more on why it doesn't need to be `volatile`?

Comment: @xvatar because volatile has a different meaning. It prevents some optimizations to prevent some concurrency issues, it doesn't denote a critical section.

Answer (score 2):

That is a horrible way of implementing a singleton (and implementing a singleton is a questionable practice in the first place...). If you are using a compiler which supports the relevant parts of C++11, you should use a static local variable:

```
template<typename T>
T& getInstance() {
    static T instance;
    return instance;
}
```

Otherwise you should use something like [call_once](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.once) from Boost.Thread:

```
//singleton.hpp
T& getInstance();

//singleton.cpp
static T* singleton;
static boost::once_flag flag=BOOST_ONCE_INIT;

static void initialize() {
    singleton = new T();
}

T& getInstance() {
    boost::call_once(flag, initialize);
    return *singleton;
}
```

Another option is to add a function to explicitly initialize your globals, and then to call that before starting any new threads.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to make the variable volatile. The mutex lock operation would tyically be implemented by a XCHG processor instruction, which also serves as a memory barrier (at least on Intel processors) - it will force the read of the variable to happen from memory, not from the cache.

Comment: does your answer hold even if there are multiple cores, every core has a cache right? so does the updates go to all the cores in time? is there a guarantee?

Comment: @Medicine, yes, marking a variable volatile basically disables caching for it. It is very costly, of course.

Comment: @Medicine: Just to clarify, the _volatile_ keyword essentially tell the compiler that "some other, unknown external thing" may eventually change the value of the variable at any point in time (example: an hardware interrupt may write something in it). You don't need it because every process will use the mutex to obtain exclusive access to the memory.

Answer (score 0):

If you have C++11, make `obj` atomic and all the problems in `getInstance` go away.

```
static std::atomic<T*> obj;
```

and

```
template <typename T, typename Lock>
std::atomic<T*> Singleton<T, Lock>::obj = 0;
```

`deleteInstance` requires a little more work:

```
T *tmp = 0;
obj.exchange(tmp);
delete tmp;
```

but `deleteInstance` is dangerous, because the class has no idea whether there are any outstanding pointers, so calling this function could yank the object out from under some innocent thread.